# Oracle join optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, left-join, query-optimization

I have the following SQL query:

```
select dres.colA, 
       dres.colP, 
       dres.ID,
       dre.ID, 
       dre.colED, 
       dre.VID,
       vpp.VID, 
       vpp.colDESC
from table1 dres
  left join table2 dre on dres.ID = dre.ID
  left join table3 vpp on vpp.VID = dre.VID    
where dre.START_TIME >=  date '2017-01-01';
```

Do you have any suggestion how the query can work better (or should look)?
Something like:

```
...where dres.ID in (select * from table2 
                     where VID in (select * from table3))....
```

Comment: for join optimiziation be sure you have proper index  on the columns   involved in join  .. and for th use of an in clause based on a subselect should be less performant thana join (normally)

Comment: and should the index help with millions of rows? i dont think so... only causes nested loops

Comment: need row counts and explain plan

Comment: there is around 500k rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `where` clause changes the outer joins to inner joins.  So, start by writing the query as:

```
select dres.colA, dres.colP, dres.ID,
       dre.ID, dre.colED, dre.VID,
       vpp.VID, vpp.colDESC
from table1 dres join
     table2 dre
     on dres.ID = dre.ID join
     table3 vpp
     on vpp.VID = dre.VID    
where dre.START_TIME >= date '2017-01-01';
```

The place to start is with indexes on `table2(id, vid, start_time, colED)` and `table3(vid, colDESC)`.

It is possible that an alternative indexing strategy would work:  `table2(start_time, id, vid, colED)`.  This would allow the `where` clause to use the index.  But that particular `where` clause may not be highly selective.

Comment: you just changed from left join to join?

Comment: @4est . . . And recommended particular indexes.

Comment: index I know....I'm wondering what will be better: do join or inside where put select?

Comment: @4est . . . `IN` would be a different query.  You can't select columns from the subqueries.